# Executing Dataflow Template via Google Cloud Scheduler

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, google-cloud-scheduler

I am trying to execute a custom Dataflow Template via the Google Cloud Scheduler but when I execute the Job I get an `UNAUTHENTICATED` exception.

How do I give Google Cloud Scheduler access to use the Dataflow google API?

Here is the URL and POST body I am using:

```
https://dataflow.googleapis.com/v1b3/projects/<<PROJECT>>/templates:launch?gcsPath=gs://<<GCS_BUCKET>>/template

{
"jobName": "job-name-scheduled",
"parameters": {
    "param1" : "parmval1"
"environment": {
    "tempLocation": "gs://<<BUCKET>>/temp",
    "region": "us-east1"
}
```

}

Comment: This page explain it all. Hope it  helps: https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/templates/executing-templates

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Cloud Scheduler documentation points out that "Targeted HTTP endpoints must be publicly accessible".

Normally, for creating that kind of Dataflow job, you would submit something like this:

```
curl   -X POST  \
   'https://dataflow.googleapis.com/v1b3/projects/<project>/templates:launch?gcsPath=gs://dataflow-templates/latest/Word_Count'  \
   -H 'Authorization: Bearer '$(gcloud auth application-default print-access-token) \
   -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
   --data '{
    "jobName": "scheduled_job",
    "parameters": {
       "inputFile" : "gs://dataflow-samples/shakespeare/kinglear.txt",
       "output": "gs://<bucket>/output/my_output"
    },
    "environment": { "zone": "us-central1-f" }
   }'
```

But, you can't send the authorization token through Cloud Scheduler.

For scheduling Dataflow jobs, you can see [this answer](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/resources/faq#is_there_a_built-in_scheduling_mechanism_to_execute_pipelines_at_given_time_or_interval) instead.